# Passing shared variable to a group or detail suppression formula

Tags: crystal-reports

My report goes:

report header suppressed

page header a (contains subreport1 which sets the shared variable showsection to "0" or "1").

page header b suppressed if showsection is 0.

page header c suppressed if showsection is 0.

group header 1 always suppressed.

details suppressed if showsection is 0.

group footer 1 suppressed if showsection is 0.

all other sections suppressed.

The problem is that if showsection is "1" the page headers are showing as designed but the details and the group footer are not showing. I simplified what the subreport is doing for testing and manually change the value to 0 or 1 depending on how I want the test to appear.

Here is my code in the subreport:

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar showsection;
showsection := 1
```

Here is the suppression formula I am using for the page header, group, and detail sections:

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar showsection;
showsection =0
```

Comment: when showsection is set to "0" everything is suppressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this matters but when I suppressed the group header this caused the Detail and group footer section suppression formula to evaluate as true. In the section expert I unchecked the Suppression box and instead marked the suppress blank section box instead.

Answer (score -1):

change supression formula like this.

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar showsection;
if showsection =0
then true
else false
```

Comment: This is functionally exactly the same as what the question states is already being used. The only difference is that it is more verbose.

Comment: I don't see any mistake in my answer... observer question carefully supress condition is wrongly written I have made that correct.. I don't think it needs a down vote.. U think this formula in question is correct and provides correct output `whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar showsection;
showsection =0`

Comment: Yes, the original formula is functionally and stylistically correct. `showsection=0` is by itself a valid boolean statement and placing it into an if-statement only serves to complicate the formula. With that in mind, your answer doesn't actually solve the problem.